# public static void main () access non static variable

Tags: java, variables, static-methods, program-entry-point, void

It is said that **non-static variables** cannot be used in a static method.  But `public static void main` does.  How is that?

Comment: Static methods can not access non-static fields, but of course you can define local variables in the method itself (and through those access non-static fields). Please give an example to clarify.

Answer (score 26):

No, it doesn't.

```
public class A {
  int a = 2;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a); // won't compile!!
  }
}
```

but

```
public class A {
  static int a = 2;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a); // this works!
  }
}
```

or if you instantiate `A`

```
public class A {
  int a = 2;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A myA = new A();
    System.out.println(myA.a); // this works too!
  }
}
```

Also

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 2;
    System.out.println(a); // this works too!
  }
}
```

will work, since `a` is a local variable here, and not an instance variable. A method local variable is always reachable during the execution of the method, regardless of if the method is `static` or not.

Comment: public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) { int a = 2;
    System.out.println(a); // this works!
  }
} my question is how does tis works

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the main method may access non-static variables, but only indirectly **through actual instances**.

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.variable = 5;
    }
}

class Example {
    public int variable;
}
```

What people mean when they say *"non-static variables cannot be used in a static method"* is that **non-static members of the same class** can't be directly accessed (as shown in [Keppils answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522055/276052) for instance).

**Related question:**

- [Accessing non-static members through the main method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893755/accessing-non-static-members-through-the-main-method-in-java)

---

**Update:**

When talking about non-static variables one implicitly means *member variables*. (Since local variables can't possible have a static modifier anyway.)

In the code

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2;
        System.out.println(a); // this works!
    }
}
```

you're declaring a *local* variable (which typically is not referred to as non-static even though it doesn't have a static modifier).

Comment: 'public class A { public static void main(String[] args) { int a = 2; System.out.println(a); // this works! } }' this doesn't use any instances

Answer (score 3):

The main method does not have access to non-static members either.

```
final public class Demo
{
   private String instanceVariable;
   private static String staticVariable;

   public String instanceMethod()
   {
      return "instance";
   }

   public static String staticMethod()
   {
      return "static";
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println(staticVariable); // ok
      System.out.println(Demo.staticMethod()); // ok

      System.out.println(new Demo().instanceMethod()); // ok
      System.out.println(new Demo().instanceVariable); // ok

      System.out.println(Demo.instanceMethod()); // wrong
      System.out.println(instanceVariable);         // wrong 
   }
}
```

This is because by default when you call a method or variable it is really accessing the `this.method()` or this.variable. But in the main() method or any other static method(), no "this" objects has yet been created.

In this sense, the static method is not a part of the object instance of the class that contains it. This is the idea behind utility classes.

To call any non-static method or variable in a static context, you need to first construct the object with a constructor or a factory like your would anywhere outside of the class.

---

More depth:

Basically it's a flaw in the design of Java IMO which allows static members (methods and fields) to be referenced *as if* they were instance members. This can be very confusing in code like this:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(runnable);
newThread.start();
newThread.sleep(1000);
```

That *looks* like it's sending the new thread to sleep, but it *actually* compiles down into code like this:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(runnable);
newThread.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

because `sleep` is a static method which only ever makes the *current* thread sleep.

Indeed, the variable isn't even checked for non-nullity (any more; it used to be, I believe):

```
Thread t = null;
t.sleep(1000);
```

Some IDEs can be configured to issue a warning or error for code like this - you shouldn't do it, as it hurts readability. (This is one of the flaws which was corrected by C#...)

Comment: so where are static methods and variable contained if not in the class they are defined in?

Comment: [when static variables are initialized in Java.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8704858/1037210)

Comment: so the only way main could access the instanceMethod and instanceVariable is if it made an object of the Demo class?

Comment: if `instanceMethod` and `instanceVariable` were instance method and instance variable respectively, then they could only be accessed from a **static method** by dereferencing them by the object of their respective class.

Answer (score 3):

**Here you can see table that clear the access of static and non-static data members in static and non-static methods. **[image: static non-static table]

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-static references in static methods like :

```
static void method() {
   A a = new A();
}
```

Same thing we do in case of `public static void main(String[] args)` method

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XYZ
{
   int i=0;

   public static void increment()
   {
       i++;   
   }
}

public class M
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XYZ o1 = new XYZ();
        XYZ o2 = new XYZ();
        o1.increment(); 
        XYZ.increment(); // system wont be able to know i belongs to which object 
                  // as it increment method (static method) can be called using class name system 
                  // will be confused changes belongs to which object.
    }
}
```